# Accessing singular_association_ids from model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using the association_collection method "other_ids" throughout my Rails app with no issues.  However whenever I try to access it from within the model defining the association, Rails has no idea what I'm taking about.  For example:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :course, :touch => true
    belongs_to  :person, :touch => true
end

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :course,    :touch => true, :counter_cache => true
    has_many    :presents,  :dependent => :delete_all
    has_many    :people,    :through => :presents

    before_destroy  :clear_attendance

    def clear_attendance
        mems = Membership.where(:course_id => course.id, :person_id => person_ids)                                                   
        mems.update_all(["attendance = attendance - ?", (1 / course.days.size.to_f)])
    end
end
```

In this case, person_ids is always null.  I've tried self.person_ids, people.ids, etc.  All nothing.  I have used day.person_ids elsewhere with no issues, so why can't I use it here?

I am using Ruby 1.9.1 and Rails 3.0.3.  Here is the SQL call from my log:

[1m[36mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "memberships" SET attendance = attendance - 0.3333333333333333 WHERE ("memberships"."course_id" = 4) AND ("memberships"."person_id" IN (NULL))[0m

edit: added more code to clarify question

Comment: do you want to get the People that :belong_to a Day?

Comment: No, that method was just an example.  I've updated the code to clarify exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help - I figured it out myself.  The problem was the order of my callbacks.  I was trying to call person_ids after the association had been deleted.  Changing the order to this solved my issues.

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_destroy  :clear_attendance

   belongs_to  :course,    :touch => true, :counter_cache => true
   has_many    :presents,  :dependent => :delete_all
   has_many    :people,    :through => :presents
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really want there is:

```
def a_method
  self.people.all
end
```

But to answer your question, `person_ids` is the correct method, and it should return an empty array, not nil. I just tried an association like that out in 2.3.10. Maybe you can post some more of your code, rails version, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've updated as you requested, including the SQL generated.